# My master page wont appear

Tags: asp.net, web-config, master-pages

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="MyAppCookie" loginUrl="~/Registration.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" path="/"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

I added this code in the configuration file and the master page wont appear whenever i load my pages. Why and how can i fix this?

Another issue that i experience is when i go to Website---> ASP configuration,, no WAT window opens!?!

Comment: What do you mean by "the master page won't appear" - the ASPX page doesn't render correctly?

Comment: Registeration.aspx. has a masterpage!.. Registration.aspx..appears but not in the context of a masterpage

Comment: If it has a master page, and it can't render in the context of that master page, you would get an error.  Are other resources on the page (CSS, images, JS) being blocked by your auth rule?

Comment: it makes a security check... i cant navigate through other pages unless i register and click submit... i think i need to add some property with the login URL property to make it work!!!

Comment: No the css rules arent blocked.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this in the web.config for one of my sites:

```
   <location path="Scripts">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Images">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```